# Python: possible data loss in multiprocessing.Queue()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have the following example, where I created a single daemon and attempt to communicate with it through event flag:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Event, Queue
import time

def reader(data):
    input_queue = data[0]
    e = data[1]
    output_queue = data[2]

    while True:
        if not e.is_set(): # if there is a signal to start
            msg = input_queue.get()         # Read from the queue 
            output_queue.put(msg)     # copy to output_queue
            if (msg == 'DONE'):  # signal to stop              
                e.set() # signal that worker is done


def writer(count, queue):
    ## Write to the queue
    for ii in range(0, count):
        queue.put(ii)             # Write 'count' numbers into the queue
    queue.put('DONE')

if __name__=='__main__':
    input_queue = Queue()   # reader() reads from queue
                          # writer() writes to queue

    output_queue = Queue()


    e = Event()
    e.set()

    reader_p = Process(target=reader, args=((input_queue, e, output_queue),))
    reader_p.daemon = True
    reader_p.start()        # Launch reader() as a separate python process

    for count in [10**4, 10**5, 10**6]:



        _start = time.time()
        writer(count, input_queue)    # Send a lot of stuff to reader()

        e.clear() # unset event, giving signal to a worker


        e.wait() # waiting for reader to finish


        # fetch results from output_queue:
        results = []
        while not output_queue.empty():
            results += [output_queue.get()]

        print(len(results)) # check how many results we have

        print("Sending %s numbers to Queue() took %s seconds" % (count, 
            (time.time() - _start)))
```

I use input and output queues, and in this example worker just copies the data to the output, which I will fetch later in the program. Everything seems Ok until the length of the data is 10k (is it actually a queue size limitation, in bytes?), but when I try to copy more elements, I have random numbers of results received, but much less than has been sent:

```
10001
Sending 10000 numbers to Queue() took 0.4259309768676758 seconds
18857
Sending 100000 numbers to Queue() took 1.693629503250122 seconds
12439
Sending 1000000 numbers to Queue() took 10.592029809951782 seconds

10001
Sending 10000 numbers to Queue() took 0.41446948051452637 seconds
46615
Sending 100000 numbers to Queue() took 1.9259979724884033 seconds
18623
Sending 1000000 numbers to Queue() took 10.06524133682251 seconds
```

---

UPDATE: Now I try to share the data between three workers. I've checked that they all are working, but the data loss did not stop:

```
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import Process, Event, Queue
import time

def reader(data):
    input_queue = data[0]
    e = data[1]
    output_queue = data[2]


    while True:
        if not e.is_set(): # if there is a signal to start

                #if not output_queue.empty(): # hangs somewhy
                msg = input_queue.get()         # Read from the queue 
                output_queue.put(msg)     # copy to output_queue
                #print("1")
                if (msg == 'DONE'):  # signal to stop              
                    e.set() # signal that there is no more data
                    print("done")



def reader1(data):
    input_queue = data[0]
    e = data[1]
    output_queue = data[2]


    while True:
        if not e.is_set(): # if there is a signal to start
                msg = input_queue.get()         # Read from the queue 
                output_queue.put(msg)     # copy to output_queue
                #print("2")
                if (msg == 'DONE'):  # signal to stop              
                    e.set() # signal that there is no more data
                    print("done")


def reader2(data):
    input_queue = data[0]
    e = data[1]
    output_queue = data[2]

    while True:
        if not e.is_set(): # if there is a signal to start
                msg = input_queue.get()         # Read from the queue 
                output_queue.put(msg)     # copy to output_queue
                #print("3")
                if (msg == 'DONE'):  # signal to stop              
                    e.set() # signal that there is no more data
                    print("done")






def writer(count, queue):
    ## Write to the queue
    for ii in range(0, count):
        queue.put(ii)             # Write 'count' numbers into the queue
    queue.put('DONE')

if __name__=='__main__':

    # I do not use manager, as it makes everything extremely slow
    #m = multiprocessing.Manager()
    #input_queue = m.Queue()

    input_queue = Queue()   # reader() reads from queue
                          # writer() writes to queue

    output_queue = Queue()


    e = Event()
    e.set()

    reader_p = Process(target=reader, args=((input_queue, e, output_queue),))
    reader_p.daemon = True
    reader_p.start()        # Launch reader() as a separate python process

    reader_p1 = Process(target=reader1, args=((input_queue, e, output_queue),))
    reader_p1.daemon = True
    reader_p1.start() 

    reader_p2 = Process(target=reader2, args=((input_queue, e, output_queue),))
    reader_p2.daemon = True
    reader_p2.start() 

    for count in [10**4, 10**5, 10**6]:


        _start = time.time()
        writer(count, input_queue)    # Send a lot of stuff to readers

        e.clear() # unset event, giving signal to a worker


        e.wait() # waiting for reader to finish


        # fetch results from output_queue:
        results = []
        while not output_queue.empty():
            results += [output_queue.get()]

        print(len(results)) # check how many results we have

        print("Sending %s numbers to Queue() took %s seconds" % (count, 
            (time.time() - _start)))
```

Results, sometimes I have second stage completed correctly:

```
done
10001
Sending 10000 numbers to Queue() took 0.37468671798706055 seconds
done
18354
Sending 100000 numbers to Queue() took 1.2723915576934814 seconds
done
34807
Sending 1000000 numbers to Queue() took 9.1871018409729 seconds

done
10001
Sending 10000 numbers to Queue() took 0.37137532234191895 seconds
done
100001
Sending 100000 numbers to Queue() took 2.5747978687286377 seconds
done
217034
Sending 1000000 numbers to Queue() took 12.640174627304077 seconds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a limit to the queue size : in multiprocessing this limit in not reliable, and once reached, the queue.put is blocked until queue has been emptied. See the documentation for more informations : https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue

In you case, this is not the issue. You just have defined a bad condition to stop fetching results :

```
while not output_queue.empty():
     results += [output_queue.get()]
```

In your case, if the writer is slower than the reader (and they will, from time to times), your queue might be empty for a brief moment, even if the writer has not finished sending everything. This is why you have an unstable number of reading.

To confirm, I replace this condition by this :

```
t0 = time.time()
while time.time()-t0<30: # seems to be enough to complete your loops, but it's just a demo condition, you should not use this
    try:
        results += [output_queue.get(timeout=1)]
    except Exception as expt: # the output_queue.get(timeout=1) will wait up to 1 second if the queue is momentarily empty. If the queue is empty for more than 1 sec, it raises an exception and it means the loop is complete. Again, this is not a good condition in real life, and this is just for testing.
        break
```